# Base class properties initialiser

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to provide a properties initialiser for a base class that would be reused by all inheriting classes. This is to allow required properties in inheriting classes without the need to manually define a constructor in each of them.:

```
class A extends Base {
  /*
    I don't want this line to throw "Property 'a' has
    no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor."
  */
  a: number
}

const a = new A({ a: 123 })
```

I figured something like this would make sense:

```
class Base<T> {
  constructor(props: T) {
    (Object.keys(props) as Array<keyof T>).forEach(key => {
      (this as T)[key] = props[key]
    })
  }

  base: number
}

class A extends Base<A> {
  a: string
}
```

But TS doesn't like `(this as T)` - this is solved by `(this as any as T)` which is obviously nonsense.

Besides, and what's more important, TS still thinks that `a` is not initialised (seems to not be aware of the `Base` constructor). Not only that - it doesn't even recognise that Base's own `base` property is initialised in the constructor.

Can this be achieved in TS? Can it be taken even further, to be able to `class B extends A<B>` without rewriting the generics logic in every class?

Assumptions:

- full strict mode
- no `!` - I want it type safe as much as possible

Comment: When you say no `!` you mean you don't want `!` in the declaration (ie `a!: number`) ? This is what `!`in  the declaration was created for

Comment: And `(this as any as T)` is not non-sense it's just a double assertion, a simple assertions still performs some checks, assertion through `any` performs no checks. In this case it's probably fine

Comment: Also why not just use `Object.assign` instead of the `keys` and `forEach`?

Comment: Ad.1. I'd have to add `!` to virtually all required properties. Doesn't that loosen my types a lot?
Ad.2. That's what I'm afraid of - no type checking here.
Ad.3. I tried, but TS didn't like that even more when `this` was treated like an object. But perhaps I'm doing something wrong here. Do you have a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would just use `Object.assign` cleaner and natively supported (or soon will be) and add a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) if the bowser is missing support for this function. To use `Object.assign` in Typescript you need to target es2015, or use the `"lib": ["es2015","dom","scripthost"]`

The simplest solution is to use a `!` (ie a definite assignment assertion)  in the declaration of the property. This is what this was created for see [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20166).

```
class Base<T> {
  constructor(props: T) {
    Object.assign(this, props)
  }

  base!: number
}

class A extends Base<A> {
  a!: string
}
```

If you really don't want to use (`!`) you can change the inheritance a bit using a function. The initialized properties will need to be specified in the `extends` clause to the class. This allows us to bypass the definite assignment checks, but it's not particularly pretty:

```
class Base<T> {
    constructor(props: T) {
        Object.assign(this, props)
    }
    base!: number // notyhing we can do about this one 
}

function withProps<TProps>(t: new <T>(props: T) => Base<T>): new () => Base<TProps> & TProps {
    return t as any;
}

class A extends withProps<{
    a: string
}>(Base) {
    m() {
        this.a; //ok
    }
}
```

We can also use this approach to enable your last scenario but it involves greater type surgery:

```
class Base<T> {
    constructor(props: T) {
        Object.assign(this, props)
    }
    base!: number // notyhing we can do about this one 
}

type FirstArgument<T extends new <U>(props: any) => any> = T extends new <U>(props: infer A) => any ? A: never
type GenericInstanceType<T extends new <U>(props: any) => any> = T extends new <U>(props: any) => infer R ? R: never
function withProps<TProps>(){
    return function<TClass extends  new <T>(props: any) => Base<T>>(t:TClass): new (props: FirstArgument<TClass> & TProps) => GenericInstanceType<TClass> & TProps {
       return t as any;
    }
}

class A extends withProps<{ a: number }>()(Base) {
    m(){
        this.a
        this.base;
    }
}

class B extends withProps<{ b: string }>()(A){
    m(){
        this.a
        this.b
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `!` is the best solution for my case, because there'll never be a situation, when the required properties are not assigned after object creation. They are assigned during creation, in the constructor of the base class. So technically it should be possible to form a generic that would catch that. I just haven't found a way yet...

Comment: And the other solution you provided is too complicated in usage and implementation - I want my code clear and readable. But thanks anyway!